# Let $f$ be continuous. Show $f(\overline{E}) \subseteq \overline{f(E)}$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $E \subseteq \mathbb R$ and $f : \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$. Show that $f(\overline{E}) \subseteq \overline{f(E)}$.

I've seen similar questions on stackexchange, but answers are using metric spaces and topology concepts I have't learned. This is from a real analysis intro class.

I'm thinking that given $g \in f(\overline{E})$, if I can show $\exists f_n \in f(E)$ s.t $f_n \rightarrow g$ where $g \in f(E)$ also, uniformly, then by definition of uniform convergence and definition of closure set, it implies $f(\overline{E}) \subseteq \overline{f(E)}$? Seems complicated

Comment: Writing $f \in f(\overline{E})$ is a rather confusing notation btw.

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to convey my attempt at a solution, but said attempt is very convoluted

Comment: Hm I was mainly pointing out that the letter $f$ is already used so you should try using a different letter for less confusion.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing some terms. If $y\in f(\overline E)$, then there exists $x\in\overline E$ with $f(x)=y$. As $x\in\overline E$, there exists $\{x_n\}\subset E$ with $x_n\to x$. Using that $f$ is continuous, 
$$
f(y)=f(\lim x_n)=\lim f(x_n)\in\overline{f(E)}.
$$

Comment: I thought about this, but wouldn't the definition of closure have to mean $f_n \rightarrow f$ for some $f  \in f(E)$, and a sequence of functions is defined to converge to $f$ if it does so $\forall x$, not just a single point $x_0$ (which $x_n$ converges to)?

Comment: That‘s what Martin means by “You are confusing some terms.” Your problem has nothing to do with convergence of functions.

Answer (score 0):

Let $e \in \overline{E}$, so $f(e)$ describes an arbitrary point of $f(\overline{E})$. You can write $e$ as the limit of some sequence. (Why?)

Check the images of that sequence under $f$. How can you now conclude that $f(e) \in \overline{f(E)}$?